# How can i send the Map Object in multipart request in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, multipart

Here I am trying to send the Object Map in the multipart request but my request is going as a string, not in JSON format please suggest me to do correct request. Thanks in advance.

I have tried the multipart request but my request should be in correct form..

```
var getApiUrl = 'http://malik-env-test.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/webapi/post/create';

  Map userData = {

    "creator": {
      "creatorId": "298",
      "createDate": "2018-12-21 20:44:45.8"
    },
    "info": "$campusInfo",
    "title": "$eventName",
    "postCampusId": "5642"

  };
```

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(getApiUrl);
   http.MultipartRequest request = new http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
   request.fields['creator'] = userData['creator'];
   request.fields['info'] = '$campusInfo';
   request.fields['title'] = '$eventName';
   request.fields['postCampusId'] = '5642';
   request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image_file1', imagePath, contentType: new MediaType('application', 'x-tar')));
//   var body = json.encode(request);
   print(request);
   http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
   String jsonData = response.toString();
   print(jsonData);ddd
```

Comment: Did the edited answer help you?

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
request.fields['userData'] = json.encode(userData);
```

You need to find out from the API spec or server owner what field name to use for the json. I've assumed `userData`.

If you want control over the media type, encoding, etc, add it as a file like this:

```
  request.files.add(
    http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
      'the_form_field name',
      utf8.encode(json.encode(userData)),
      contentType: MediaType(
        'application',
        'json',
        {'charset': 'utf-8'},
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: I have checked this solution request is going as a string, not as JSON format, can you please help me out how to make it as a JSON format request

Comment: Edited the answer to show how to set the media type.

Comment: works fine. @RichardHeap you can import http-parse package

Answer (score 1):

I think, the easiest way to add object fields is using  brackets like this ;

```
request.fields['creator[creatorId]'] = '$creatorId';
request.fields['creator[createDate]'] = '$createDate';
request.fields['title'] = '$eventName';
request.fields['postCampusId'] = '5642';
```

So, for the fields inside another you need to put the object name first then add to fields name inside brackets.

this should work just fine.

Answer (score -3):

```
   var userData = json.encode({
     "creator": {
           "creatorId": "298",
            "createDate": "2018-12-21 20:44:45.8"
       },
      "info": "$campusInfo",
      "title": "$eventName",
      "postCampusId": "5642"
    });
    var client = http.Client();
    client
        .post('https://'+ url ,
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: userData )
```

Comment: what should be body here..? and I need multipart request so that I could be able to send the image as well